# VBA code how to select a dropdown list

Tags: vba, excel

Need help, I have the below code that logs you in, moves to the right page, selects the table data and copies it, but the issue is there is a drop down list as shown with code, how do I get the code to select the "All" and how do I write that? I am willing to pay some to get this answer fast.

The data from web page for the drop down is here:

```
"<select name="flightrisk_tbl_length" aria-controls="flightrisk_tbl"      class="form-control input-sm"><option value="5">5</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="-1">All</option></select>"


Sub GetTable()

Dim ieApp As InternetExplorer
Dim ieDoc As Object
Dim ieTable As Object
Dim clip As DataObject


'create a new instance of ie
Set ieApp = New InternetExplorer

'you don’t need this, but it’s good for debugging
ieApp.Visible = True

'assume we’re not logged in and just go directly to the login page
ieApp.Navigate "xxxx"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document

'fill in the login form – View Source from your browser to get the control   names
With ieDoc.forms(0)
.UserName.Value = "xxxx"
.Password.Value = "xxxx"
.submit
End With
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

'now that we’re in, go to the page we want
ieApp.Navigate "xxxx"
Do While ieApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop



'get the table based on the table’s id
Set ieDoc = ieApp.Document
Set ieTable = ieDoc.All.Item("flightrisk_tbl")


'copy the tables html to the clipboard and paste to the sheet
If Not ieTable Is Nothing Then
Set clip = New DataObject
clip.SetText "" & ieTable.outerHTML & ""
clip.PutInClipboard
Sheet12.Select
Sheet12.Range("A1").Select
Sheet12.PasteSpecial "Unicode Text"
End If

'close 'er up
ieApp.Quit
Set ieApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `GetElementsByName` method to get the dropdown object:

```
Dim oDropDown as object
Set oDropDown = ieApp.GetElementsByName("flightrisk_tbl_length")(0) 'Use zero, because this returns an array of all elements with the same name.
```

Afterwards, you can use the `innerHTML` or use the `GetElementsByClassName` method to get everything from the option classes.